Convert a real number into binary - assembly
I need to convert the entered real number into binary through assembler. I have this same code, only with integers and it works, but not here. When I enter with a period, e.g. 3.1 throws an error and stops the program, and when I enter with a comma, e.g. the 3,1 console just sits there and nothing happens.
includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib
includelib ucrt.lib

EXTERN printf: PROC
EXTERN scanf: PROC
EXTERN exit: PROC

.data
unos BYTE "Unesite dva realna broja: ", 0              
ispis BYTE "Broj 1: %f (binarno): %s \nBroj 2: %f (binarno): %s \n", 0  
formatStr BYTE "%f", 0                                 
a REAL4 ?                                              
b REAL4 ?                                              
binBr1 BYTE 33 DUP(?)                                    
binBr2 BYTE 33 DUP(?)                                   

.code
public asmReal

konverBin proc
    push rbx                                            
    mov rbx, rdi                                        
    mov ecx, 32                                         

convertLoop:
    shl eax, 1                                          
    mov byte ptr [rbx], '0'                             
    adc byte ptr [rbx], 0                               
    add rbx, 1                                          
    loop convertLoop                                    

    mov byte ptr [rbx], 0                                       
    pop rbx                                             
    ret         
konverBin endp


asmReal proc
    lea     rcx, unos                                   
    call    printf                                      

input_a:
    lea     rcx, formatStr                              
    lea     rdx, a                                      
    call    scanf                                       
    cmp     eax, 1                                      
    jne     input_a                                    

input_b:
    lea     rcx, formatStr                              
    lea     rdx, b                                      
    call    scanf                                       
    cmp     eax, 1                                      
    jne     input_b                                     


    lea     rdi, binBr1
    mov     eax, dword ptr [a]
    call    konverBin


    lea     rdi, binBr2
    mov     eax, dword ptr [b]
    call    konverBin


    mov     rcx, OFFSET ispis
    movss   xmm0, dword ptr [a]                         
    movss   xmm1, dword ptr [b]                         
    lea     r8, binBr1
    lea     r9, binBr2
    call    printf

    xor     ecx, ecx                                    
    call    exit                                        

asmReal endp
END

This is the error and exception when working with period (e.g. 3.1):
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD529CB524 (ucrtbase.dll) in nekoeko.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
In stdio.h:
#else
{
    return __stdio_common_vfprintf(_CRT_INTERNAL_LOCAL_PRINTF_OPTIONS, _Stream, _Format, _Locale, _ArgList);
}
#endif


The asmReal function doesn't fix up the alignment of rsp before calling functions. rsp needs to be 16-aligned before a call, so the alignment is off by 8 on function entry, so you need to fix it again before calling other functions. A lot of the time when calling your own functions you can get away with not restoring alignment, but some function you call may save XMM registers to the stack with an aligned store such as movaps, which would fail.

Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

You would get this exact error, about reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, when actually writing to some arbitrary (not necessarily 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) unaligned location with movaps. The error message is just wrong.
Additionally, this code:

mov     rcx, OFFSET ispis
movss   xmm0, dword ptr [a]                         
movss   xmm1, dword ptr [b]                         
lea     r8, binBr1
lea     r9, binBr2
call    printf


Does not correctly pass arguments to printf.
The first 4 arguments can be passed in registers, but unlike in SysV AMD64 ABI, in the Win64 ABI that means only the first 4 even if they are some mix of integer and floating point values. You don't get "extra slots" by mixing types. If the first argument is an integer/pointer argument in rcx, the second slot is still xmm1, xmm0 is skipped.
Also, for a varargs function you have to pass floats in two registers (both the xmm register but also the integer register of the same "slot" so eg both xmm1 and rdx) (I don't know if that will actually matter for printf, but it's a rule for varargs in general), and they have to be converted to doubles:

For floating-point values only, both the integer register and the
floating-point register must contain the value, in case the callee
expects the value in the integer registers.

Since there are 5 arguments, the last argument would be on the stack.

I expect it would matter for printf; its access to its variadic args is data-dependent on the format string, so it couldn't plausibly optimize down to just reading XMM1 at some point.  The point of the design is to allow variadic functions to only dump the 4 integer regs to the shadow space to make a contiguous array of args on the stack which variadic functions can iterate over, so it almost certainly just does that, not reading any XMM regs.
